# Changing background when variable exceeds a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What I'm trying to do is give a div another class when the variable that i use to determine the width of that element exceeds a certain value. How can I add a class to the appropriate element when the value exceeds 70? As you can see the elements that belongs to the variable has the same name as ID.

this is my code:

```
       //serverload bars 
       var serverload1 = 73;
       var serverload2 = 13;
       var serverload3 = 68;
       var serverload4 = 33;
       var serverload5 = 83;
       var serverload6 = 63;
       var serverload7 = 93;
       var serverload8 = 23;

       $('#serverload1').width(serverload1+"%");
       $('#serverload2').width(serverload2+"%");
       $('#serverload3').width(serverload3+"%");
       $('#serverload4').width(serverload4+"%");
       $('#serverload5').width(serverload5+"%");
       $('#serverload6').width(serverload6+"%");
       $('#serverload7').width(serverload7+"%");
       $('#serverload8').width(serverload8+"%");

       var barcolors = [serverload1, serverload2, serverload3, serverload4, serverload5, serverload6, serverload7, serverload8].forEach(testwidth);


       function testwidth(element, index, array) {
           if (element > 70) {
            console.log(element);
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to restructure your code in the following way:

```
var barcolors = [73, 13, 68, 33, 83, 63, 93, 23];

$("[id^=serverload]").filter(function() {
    var i = this.id.substring(10),
        width = barcolors[i-1];

    if (width !== undefined)
        this.style.width = width + "%";

    return width > 70;
}).addClass("someClass");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JaqGJ/

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
   function testwidth(element, index, array) {
       if (element > 70) {
         $('#' + element).addClass('mynewclass');
       }
   }
```

Comment: this will yield $('#73').addClass('mynewclass');

Answer (score 1):

Based on your combined responses I was able to work out the following solution:

```
 var barcolors = [["serverload1",serverload1], ["serverload2",serverload2], ["serverload3",serverload3], ["serverload4",serverload4], ["serverload5",serverload5], ["serverload6",serverload6], ["serverload7",serverload7], ["serverload8",serverload8]].forEach(testwidth);


       function testwidth(element, index, array) {
           if (element[1] > 70) {
            console.log(element[0]);
            var tegroot = "#"+element[0];
            console.log(tegroot);
            $(tegroot).addClass("redbar");
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on VisioN's solution, but more generic:

http://jsfiddle.net/JaqGJ/1/

```
var barcolors = [73, 13, 68, 33, 83, 63, 93, 23];

$(".bar").filter(function(i) {
    var width = barcolors[i];

    this.style.width = width ?  width + "%" : 0;

    return width > 70;
}).addClass("someClass");
```

Note: the last bar number 9 is just to test code safety.

Comment: But what is more generic here? You set width `0` to *undefined* blocks. It is wrong, since width should be either `auto` or not set. Moreover, I haven't used classes and `i` argument of handler function because in DOM tree the blocks may be listed in *unsorted* way, e.g. `#serverload3`, `#serverload1`, `#serverload2`.

Comment: Well you could argue if it's more generic to rely on the sorting of divs in HTML or if their ID's are always `#serverloadx` ;) (substring(10)). It is more generic as you don't have to set IDs on every div and I think undefined blocks should rather have 0 width instead of auto (or not set, which results in auto for block elements) because the latter would indicate they are at 100%. Note that you could also use an `ul > li` construct instead of adding a class to every div.

Comment: Plus I don't even really rely on HTML, my code does not rely on any HTML but the class selector (which could be any selector). Which bar gets what width is defined in the barcolors array.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

`.addClass()` for adding a class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(serverload1>70){
   $('#serverload1').addClass('NEW CLASS NAME');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment than an answer but:

Have you thought about putting the load value in a data attribute of the html elements?

```
<div id="serverload1" class="serverload" data-load="73"></div>
<div id="serverload2" class="serverload" data-load="13"></div>
```

the js would be quite smaller and more readable:

```
$('div.serverload').filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        load = $this.data('load');
    $this.width(load + '%');
    return load > 70;
}).addClass('customClass');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5cXwb/9/